# The <f:ajax event="valueChange" /> won't get triggered due to a <h:selectOneListbox /> with only one element/item

Tags: java, jsf, listbox, listboxitem

My `<h:selectOneListbox />` works well when it contains more than one element, but a problem occurs when there is only one single item: the listbox get displayed as a dropdown list, and my nested `<f:ajax event="valueChange" />` won't get triggered. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I just added a `size` attribute to the `<h:selectOneListbox />` tag with a value of `2` and it solved the problem:

```xml
<h:selectOneListbox size="2" />
```

Hope that could help `;)`

Answer (score 0):

Cause there is no change event... there is only one item to select...

Try adding

```
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Item..." noSelectionOption="true" />
```

---

INMO its a wrong design to have `<h:selectOneListbox` with a single value and ask the user to change it...

Consider adding `render="#{mybean.myList gt 1}"` to your `<h:selectOneListbox` and adding some other element (like commandButton or whatever with `render="#{mybean.myList eq 1}"`)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but in fact, I'm using the `<f:selectItems />` tag, and the list I get in its `value` attribute contains only one item. I tried to add the attribute you put forward to this tag too, but it doesn't work.

Comment: add the `<f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Item..." noSelectionOption="true" />` in addition to your `<f:selectItems`...

Comment: I'm not allowed to add a `Select Item...` label... thanks anyway!